# jQuery POST data is not sent to proper page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am trying to send some data using POST between pages using javascript when the user clicks a button. However, when I try to index the POST variables using php on the page I send the data to, it says that it does not exist.

I was using developer tools in chrome to see what the problem was when I noticed that a "copy" page was created while I was sent to the page where the POST variables don't exist.

In the network's header tab, under form data I saw all of the post variables and the preview of the page is what I want it to be.

**The form data:**
name: John
lname: Stilton

**Here's my html and javascript on my first page:**

```
<button type="button" onclick="makePost(); window.location.href='person.php'" id="person">View Person</button>

<script>
function makePost(){
  var url = "person.php"
  $.post(url,
  {name: "John",
  lname: "Stilton"});
}
</script>
```

**On my php page I'm just echoing the POST data so there's nothing wrong there:**

```
<?php
echo($_POST['name']);
echo($_POST['lname']);
?>
```

I know I can use a form to do this, but I'm trying to avoid it. Please help me find out what is wrong with where my POST data is going.

Edit: So it seems like the problem is how I'm redirecting the user to the page. How can I redirect the user with the POST data to the same page?

Comment: You are doing a redirect also to that page. That is a completely separate request than the ajax one and does not contain the post data. Use the complete callback of `$.post` and get rid of the redirect

Comment: You either need to use ajax to post your data to person.php or add a `<form>` to your html with `methos="post"` and submit it to person.php. Either way, redirecting to person.php using `window.location.href='person.php'` is incorrect if you want to post your data.